# TestNG and JPA not sure what's going on... but my test fails

Tags: java, hibernate, testng

I am running some persistence tests and when I use the method create or create-drop... my test fails when I use update it succeed.

My test is composed of 2 methods, one creates an user in the BD the other method searches for this user.

Both are @Test and I an using Groups and DependsOnGroups to make then execute in the order I need.(insert before search)

What I have noticed is that when the second test runs the table is empty... does Hibernate cleans the tables after every test ? why does it work with update in Hibernate settings ?

Comment: we need more details. Besides: You can't rely on the output of @Test method1 in @Test method2. Ever.

Comment: Yes you can, it's pretty standard in functional testing (e.g. database, Selenium, etc...). cfontes: we do need more details, like the code of your test methods and the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your first test isn't flushing to the db. Try explicitly flushing.

session.flush();